# How can I retrieve a value from my PostgreSQL database and print it in my html website?

Tags: django, postgresql

I am trying to take information that is submitted by the user in a form, and make a query to my PostgreSQL database to retrieve the average cost of the selected repair. While I can retrieve the value, I can only do so in the scope of the (if request.method == POST) statement.

Is there a way I can retrieve the cleaned_data from my form and filter the database entries outside of the scope?

Here is the code in my views.py file that contains the problematic code:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404

from .forms import ModelCreationForm
from .models import Make, Model, Car, Repair, Cost

def model_create_view(request):
    form = ModelCreationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ModelCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            cost_data = getFormData(request, form)
            return redirect('model_add')
    return render(request, 'models/home.html', {"form": form})
def getFormData(request, form):
        year = form.cleaned_data['year']
        make = form.cleaned_data['make']
        model = form.cleaned_data['model']
        repair = form.cleaned_data['repair']
        form_data = Cost.objects.filter(year = year, make = make, model = model, repair = repair)
        return render(request, 'models/home.html', {"cost": form_data[0]})
def model_update_view(request, pk):
    car = get_object_or_404(Car, pk=pk)
    form = ModelCreationForm(instance=car)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ModelCreationForm(request.POST, instance=car)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('model_change', pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'models/home.html', {'form': form})

def load_models(request):
    make_id = request.GET.get('make_id')
    year_id = request.GET.get('year_id')
    models = list(Model.objects.filter(year__id = year_id, make__id = make_id).values())
    return JsonResponse({'models': models})
    # return JsonResponse(list(cities.values('id', 'name')), safe=False)
def load_repairs(request):
    make_id = request.GET.get('make_id')
    year_id = request.GET.get('year_id')
    model_id = request.GET.get('model_id')
    repairs = list(Repair.objects.filter(year__id = year_id, make__id = make_id, model__id=model_id).values())
    return JsonResponse({'repairs': repairs})
def load_about(request):
    return render(request, 'models/about_autobuddy.html')

def load_autobuddy_estimator(request):
    return render(request, 'models/autobuddy_estimator.html')

def load_is_it_fair(request):
    return render(request, 'models/is_it_fair.html')

def load_make_a_report(request):
    return render(request, 'models/make_report.html')
```

Code in my urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.model_create_view, name='model_add'),
    path('about_autobuddy/', views.load_about, name='load_about'),
    path('autobuddy_estimator/', views.load_autobuddy_estimator, name='load_estimator'),
    path('autobuddy_is_it_fair/', views.load_is_it_fair, name='load_fair'),
    path('autobuddy_make_report/', views.load_make_a_report, name='load_reporter'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.model_update_view, name='model_change'),
    path('ajax/load-models/', views.load_models, name='ajax_load_models'), # AJAX
    path('ajax/load-repairs/', views.load_repairs, name='ajax_load_repairs'), # AJAX
]
```

Code in my forms.py file:
from django import forms

```
from autobuddyapp.models import Make, Model, Car, Repair

class ModelCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['model'].queryset = Model.objects.none()
        self.fields['repair'].queryset = Repair.objects.none()
        if 'make' and 'year' and 'model' in self.data:
            try:
                year_id = int(self.data.get('year'))
                make_id = int(self.data.get('make'))
                self.fields['model'].queryset = Model.objects.filter(year_id=year_id, make_id=make_id).order_by('name')
                model_id = int(self.data.get('model'))
                self.fields['repair'].queryset = Repair.objects.filter(year_id=year_id, make_id=make_id, model_id=model_id).order_by('repair')

            except (ValueError, TypeError): 
                pass  # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty City queryset
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['model'].queryset = self.instance.model.make_set.order_by('name')
            self.fields['repair'].queryset = self.instance.repair.make_set.order_by('repair')
```

Code in my model.py file:

```
from django.db import models

class Year (models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.year)
class Make (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Model(models.Model):
    year = models.ForeignKey(Year, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    make = models.ForeignKey(Make, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " (" + str(self.year) + ")"

class Repair(models.Model):
    year = models.ForeignKey(Year, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    make = models.ForeignKey(Make, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    repair = models.CharField(max_length = 40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.repair + " (" + str(self.make) + " " + str(self.model) + ")"

class Car(models.Model):
    year = models.ForeignKey(Year, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    make = models.ForeignKey(Make, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    repair = models.ForeignKey(Repair, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name = 'car_part')
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.make) + " " + str(self.model)

class Cost(models.Model):
    year = models.ForeignKey(Year, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    make = models.ForeignKey(Make, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    repair = models.ForeignKey(Repair, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name = 'cost_car_part')
    cost = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "$" + str(self.cost)
```

Code in my home.html file that the form resides in:

```
    {% load static %}

    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/edits.css' %}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Welcome to AutoBuddy!</title>

    </head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var element_position = $("#toolbarContainer").offset().top;
            var scroll_position = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scroll_position > 472.4375) {
                $("#toolbarContainer").css("position", "fixed");
                $("#toolbarContainer").css("top", "-30px");
                $("#toolbarContainer").css("right", "0px");
            }
            else if (scroll_position <= 472.4375) {
                $("#toolbarContainer").css("position", "static");
                $("#toolbarContainer").css("top", "472.4375px");
            }
        })

        function goToAbout() {
            document.location.href = "{% url 'load_about' %}"
        }

        function goToEstimator() {
                document.location.href = "{% url 'load_estimator' %}"
        }

        function goToIsItFair() {
            document.location.href = "{% url 'load_fair' %}"
        }

        function goToReporter() {
            document.location.href = "{% url 'load_reporter' %}"
        }

    </script>


    <body style="background-color: rgb(252, 20, 20);">
    <div id = "intro" style = "text-align: center;">
        <h1 style="font-family: neuton; color: white;">Welcome to AutoBuddy!</h1>
        <div id="imageContainer" style='margin-top: 80px;'>
            <img src= "{% static '/images/logo-color.png' %}" alt='AutoBuddy Logo' width="300" height="300" >
        </div>

        <div id="toolbarContainer" style = "margin-top: 30px; width: 100%; background-color: rgb(252, 20, 20);">
            <button class="toolbarButton" onclick="goToAbout()" type="button" style = "font-family: neuton; right: 200px">
                About AutoBuddy
            </button>
            <button class="toolbarButton" onclick="goToEstimator()" type=button style = "font-family: neuton; right: 100px">
                AutoBuddy Repair Estimator
            </button>

            <button class="toolbarButton" onclick = "goToIsItFair()" type="button" style="font-family: neuton; left: 30px">
                Is It Fair Estimator Tool
            </button>

            <button class = "toolbarButton" onclick="goToReporter()" type="button" style="font-family: neuton; left: 130px">
                Make a Report!
            </button>
        </div>
        
        <p style='font-family: neuton; color: white; font-size: 20px; margin-top: 100px;'>
            Welcome to AutoBuddy, the auto repair estimator that calculates estimates
            based on user reports submitted by real people! <br> Here, you can chose to
            estimate what you're going to pay at the shop. You can also check to see whether
            the shop is charging you a fair price. <br> Of course, if you recently paid a mechanic
            to fix your car up, you can help us out by submitting a report on what you paid,
            <br>which parts were replaced, where you took your car, and the car you brought in.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id = "AboutAutoBuddy" style="font-family: neuton; margin-top: 250px; margin-left: 40px">
        <h2 style="color: white; text-align: left;">
            About AutoBuddy
        </h2>
        <p style = 'color: white; font-size: 20px; text-align:left; margin-top: 0px;'> 
            The idea for AutoBuddy came to me after experimenting with a few auto repair estimators. <br>
            As I used these estimators, I became inspired to create my own, however, I would add my own spins on it. <br>
            Instead of pulling numbers from external sources, AutoBuddy's estimates are calculated from reports that are <br> 
            submitted by actual users.
        </p>
        <p style = 'color: white; font-size: 20px; text-align:left; margin-top: 50px;'>
            AutoBuddy also offers users a tool to check if a quote they got from the shop is reasonably priced. <br>
            The Is It Fair tool works the same way as the AutoBuddy Estimator, except that the tool presents the <br>
            user with a graphical colored spectrum that'll help users with determining the fairness of their quote. <br>
        </p>
        <p style='color: white; font-size: 20px; text-align:left; margin-top: 50px;'> 
            The goal that AutoBuddy strives to acheive is to help users save money on auto repair by giving them the tools<br>
            to avoid being taken advantage of from high auto repair prices. 
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="AutoBuddyEstimator" style = "font-family: neuton; margin-top: 250px; margin-left: 40px">
        <h2 style="color: white; text-align: left;">
            AutoBuddy Estimator
        </h2>
        <p style='color: white; font-size: 20px; text-align:left; margin-top: 50px;'>
            As mentioned in the About AutoBuddy section, the AutoBuddy Estimator takes the car and repair info submitted <br>
            by the user, and sends it to an API that will calculate the estimate for the part(s) sent by the user. <br>
            AutoBuddy uses a Postgreql database to store information on cars, users, and reports, which will later be used <br>
            to calculate the estimate.
        </p>
        <p style = "color: white; font-size: 20px; text-align:left; margin-top: 50px;">
            The user will be asked to select his/her vehicle's year, make, and model from three <br> 
            dropdown buttons. Upon clicking the "submit" button, he/she will be presented with the estimated total cost of <br>
            repair. If multiple repairs were selected, then the estimated costs of each repair will also be displayed. <br> 
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="IsItFair" style = "font-family: neuton; margin-top: 250px; margin-left: 40px">
        <h2 style = "color: white; text-align: left;">
            Is It Fair
        </h2>
        <p style = "color: white; font-size: 20px; text-align:left; margin-top: 50px;">
            The Is It Fair tool acts kind of like a shield to users in that it can protect them from overpriced auto repairs. <br>
            Its primary purpose is to compare the user-submitted costs for specific repairs to their averages calculated by the API. <br>
            The tool would then display a colored spectrum that will notify the user whether or not they're paying too much. <br>
        </p>                 

        <p style = "color: white; font-size: 20px; text-align:left; margin-top: 50px;">
            The Is It Fair spectrum will display one of four colors to the user, depending on how cheap or expensive the quote is <br>
            relative to the calculated average. The four colors are: Dark Green, Green, Yellow, and Red. 
        </p>
        <p style="color: white; font-size: 20px; text-align:left; margin-top: 50px;">
            Dark Green indicates that the user's quote for their submitted repairs is significantly below the calculated average, and that the user is getting <br>
            one heck of a deal! 
        </p>
        <p style="color: white; font-size: 20px; text-align:left; margin-top: 50px;">
            Green indicates that the user's quote is either slightly below or at the calculated average, and is either getting <br>
            somewhat of a deal, or is at least getting charged the average price.  
        </p>
        <p style = "color: white; font-size: 20px; text-align:left; margin-top: 50px;">
            Yellow indicates that the user's quote is slightly above the calculated average price. The user is kind of paying <br>
            more than they should, but they are certainly not getting their head knocked off.
        </p>
        <p style = "color: white; font-size: 20px; text-align:left; margin-top: 50px;">
            Red indicates that the user's quote is significantly above the calculated average and that he/she should probably <br>
            find a different mechanic.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="MakeAReport" style = "font-family: neuton; margin-top: 250px; margin-left: 40px;">
        <h2 style = "color: white; text-align: left;">
            Making A Report
        </h2>
        <p style = "color: white; font-size: 20px; text-align:left; margin-top: 50px;">
            If you've recently taken your car to your local mechanic and are felling particularly helpful, feel free to send <br>
            a report to AutoBuddy!
        <p style = "color: white; font-size: 20px; text-align:left; margin-top: 50px;">
            To send AutoBuddy a report of your auto repair costs, click on the "Make a Report!" button. <br> 
            You will be prompted to enter in your first and last name, along with your vehicle's information <br>
            just like you would in the AutoBuddy Estimator and Is It Fair? tools.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id = 'header&form' style="text-align: center;">
        <h2>Car Form</h2>
        <form method="post" id="modelForm" data-models-url="{% url 'ajax_load_models' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" name = 'submit' value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#id_make").change(function () {
            const url = $("#modelForm").attr("data-models-url");  // get the url of the `load_cities` view
            const yearId = $("#id_year").val();
            const makeId = $(this).val();  // get the selected country ID from the HTML input
            $.ajax({    
                                // initialize an AJAX request
                url: url,                    // set the url of the request (= /persons/ajax/load-cities/ )
                data: {
                    'year_id': yearId,
                    'make_id': makeId,       // add the country id to the GET parameters
                },
                success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
                    $("#id_model").html(data);  // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
                    console.log(data);
                    for (let i = 0; i < data.models.length; i++) {
                        var option = $('<option/>');
                        option.attr({ 'value': data.models[i].id }).text(data.models[i].name);
                        $('#id_model').append(option);
                    }
                    /*
                    let html_data = '<option value="">---------</option>';
                    data.forEach(function (city) {
                        html_data += `<option value="${city.id}">${city.name}</option>`
                    });
                    console.log(html_data);
                    $("#id_city").html(html_data);
                    */
                }
            });


        });
        $("#id_model").change(function () {
            const repairUrl = "{% url 'ajax_load_repairs' %}";
            const yearId = $("#id_year").val();
            const makeId = $("#id_make").val();
            const modelId = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({    
                                // initialize an AJAX request
                url: repairUrl,    // set the url of the request (= /persons/ajax/load-repairs/ )
                data: {
                    'year_id': yearId,
                    'make_id': makeId,       // add the country id to the GET parameters
                    'model_id': modelId,
                },
                success: function (data) {   // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function;
                    $("#id_repair").html(data);  // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
                    for (let i = 0; i < data.repairs.length; i++) {
                        var option = $('<option/>');
                        option.attr({ 'value': data.repairs[i].id }).text(data.repairs[i].repair);
                        $('#id_repair').append(option);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can only access `form.cleaned_data` only after executing `form.is_valid()`, but you need  to initialize the form with the POSTed data, so no, you can't do the filtering you want, without having your `POST` data.

Comment: Is there a way to pass the filtering over to a variable outside of the if statement?

Comment: Yes, but you need to send your parameters as GET. You've done it in your load_* views.

Comment: But how would you send them as GET?